# Email address as username in svn+ssh login?

Tags: svn, authentication, ssh

I need to allow access to an svn repository using email addresses as the user name. I can log in to the server over ssh no problem by changing the email address "@" to a "$" like so:

```
ssh user.name$mydomain.com@mydomain.com
```

Unfortunately, the same does not work for svn+ssh. This gets me nowhere:

```
svn ls svn+ssh://user.name$mydomain.com@mydomain.com/home/accountname/data/svn/repos
```

Anyone know how this is usually done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a URL, have you tried URL-encoding the @ sign? I don't know if this would work, but you could try `user.name%40mydomain.com`.

Comment: Ha! The URL encoding didn't work, but the % (instead of the $) is what was needed. So the login string is actually:

svn ls svn+ssh://user.name%mydomain.com@mydomain.com/home/accountname/data/svn/repos

I wouldn't have found that without this suggestion. 

Thanks!

Comment: Weird. I wouldn't have thought that you could substitute either of those characters ($ in ssh or % in svn+ssh) for the @ character. In fact, I would think that $mydomain in the SSH command gets replaced by an empty string, so you end up with user.name.com in that case. But hey, if it works, great!

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer says, if you're on a UNIX box, your shell program is probably trying to replace the $ as if it was a variable. Try escaping the "$" sign by including a backslash before it like this:

```
svn ls svn+ssh://user.name\$mydomain.com@mydomain.com/home/accountname/data/svn/repos
```

Alternatively, if you use single quotes around the URL, BASH or whatever shell you are using should not try to replace the $.

```
svn ls 'svn+ssh://user.name$mydomain.com@mydomain.com/home/accountname/data/svn/repos'
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the $ being replaced by the shell you are using? And SVN has only usernames instead of user+email for authentication. I assume this wouldn't work.

Comment: I've been careful to create both the ssh connection and the svn connection the same way in the same shell, so I'd have expected the credentials to be handled the same, too. I've tried dropping the "@mydomain.com" (plus lots of other variations) and I get the same result. The problem is that on my host, the username _is_ an email address. I just don't know if the authentication is managed by svn or passed through directly to ssh or something somewhere in between.